# How to programmatically change the SQLite DbContext connection string?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

How to programmatically change the SQLite DbContext connection string?

The goal: to make the user in the process of the application could select different SQLite database files through the dialog.
How to do this so that after selecting in the dialog, the path to the database changes.
Or change the connection string in App.config.

Is used:
**Nuget:** System.Data.SQLite;
**Application:** Console. NET Framework.

I would not like to install additional libraries..
But if there is a need, then you can...

Project - https://github.com/jhon65496/SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw

[image]

**Method-1**
If you use this method of creating

```cs
string path = @"C:\Projects\dbAppIndexes3.db";
string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";
DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionString);
```

Then the code does not return anything.

**Method-2**
If you use this method of creation.
I.e. by changing the App.config, then
`GetAll1()` works fine, and `GetAll2()` reads the path to the database from App.config, and the path is the previous one.

```cs
GetAll1();
GetAll2();
```

**packages.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.4.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.118.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

**App.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=dbAppIndexes.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

**Index**

```cs
[Table("Indexes")]
public class Index
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }        
}
```

**AppService**

```cs
class AppService
{
    public AppService()
    {
        
        TestMain();
    }



    public void TestMain()
    {
        // Test 1
        // GetAll();
        
        // Test 2
           GetAll1();
           GetAll2();
    }   

    public void GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            // 
            // string path = @"C:\Projects\dbAppIndexes3.db";
            // string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";
            // DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionString);


            // 
            string connectionStringsName = "DefaultConnection2";
            DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionStringsName);

            IndexesRepository indexesRepository = new IndexesRepository(dbContextIndexes);

            var i = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
            var indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(i);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string s = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }            
    }



    public void GetAll1()
    {
        AppSettingService appSettingService = new AppSettingService();
        
        string path = @"C:\Projects\dbAppIndexes3.db";
        string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";
        string connectionStringName = @"DefaultConnection";

        appSettingService.SaveConnectionString(connectionStringName, connectionString);
        
        DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionStringName);

        IndexesRepository indexesRepository = new IndexesRepository(dbContextIndexes);

        var i = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
        var indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(i);
    }

    public void GetAll2()
    {
        AppSettingService appSettingService = new AppSettingService();

        string path = @"C:\Projects\dbAppIndexes4.db";
        string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";
        string connectionStringName = @"DefaultConnection";

        appSettingService.SaveConnectionString(connectionStringName, connectionString);

        DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionStringName);

        IndexesRepository indexesRepository = new IndexesRepository(dbContextIndexes);

        var i = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
        var indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(i);
    }


}
```

**IndexesRepository**

```cs
class IndexesRepository 
{

    DbContextIndexes _db;
    #region Конструктор --- --- --- ---
    public IndexesRepository(DbContextIndexes db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    #endregion

    public IQueryable<Index> Items => _db.Indexes;

}
```

**DbContextIndexes**

```cs
public class DbContextIndexes : DbContext
{

    public DbContextIndexes() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    
    public DbContextIndexes(string connectionStringsName) : base(connectionStringsName)
    {

    }
    
    public DbSet<Index> Indexes { get; set; }        
}
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Console.ReadKey();
    AppService appService = new AppService();
}
```

---

### Done-1. Error

Based on the materials: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77575278/10530657
Project:  https://github.com/jhon65496/SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw/tree/steve-py01
Commit:  https://github.com/jhon65496/SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw/compare/master...steve-py01

Result: Error

```
Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.
```

I get in the line `var i = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();`.
Method.

```cs
public void GetAll3()
{
    string path = @"c:\TestFile\DBTest\SQLite\01\dbAppIndexes3.db";
    string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";

    DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionString);

    IndexesRepository indexesRepository = new IndexesRepository(dbContextIndexes);

    var i = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
    var indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(i);
}
```

**DbContextIndexes**

```cs
public class DbContextIndexes : DbContext
{
    public DbContextIndexes() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    
    //public DbContextIndexes(string connectionStringsName) : base(connectionStringsName)
    //{

    //}

    public DbContextIndexes(string connectionString) : this() // Use "DefaultConnection" app connection string and
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; // Overwrite to use the desired connection string.
    }

    public DbSet<Index> Indexes { get; set; }        
}
```

**AppService**

```cs
class AppService
{
    public AppService()
    {
        
        TestMain();
    }

    public void TestMain()
    {    
        // Отв--steve-py--stackoverflow.com
        GetAll3();
        GetAll4();
    }

    #region steve-py--stackoverflow.com --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
    public void GetAll3()
    {
        string path = @"c:\TestFile\DBTest\SQLite\01\dbAppIndexes3.db";
        string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";

        DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionString);

        IndexesRepository indexesRepository = new IndexesRepository(dbContextIndexes);

        var i = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
        var indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(i);
    }

    public void GetAll4()
    {
        string path = @"c:\TestFile\DBTest\SQLite\01\dbAppIndexes4.db";
        string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";

        DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionString);

        IndexesRepository indexesRepository = new IndexesRepository(dbContextIndexes);

        var i = indexesRepository.Items.ToArray();
        var indexes = new ObservableCollection<Index>(i);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Сообщение = Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.
  Источник = EntityFramework.SqlServer
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetOrGenerateDatabaseNameAndGetFileNames(SqlConnection sqlConnection, String& databaseName, String& dataFileName, String& logFileName)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   в System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

  Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.AppService.GetAll3() в AppService.cs
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.AppService.TestMain() в AppService.cs
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.AppService.AppService() в AppService.cs
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.Program.Main(string[]) в Program.cs
```

**Pic-1**
[image]

**Pic-2**
[image]

---

## Done-2. Error

[image]

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Cannot create file 'C:\Users\Root\DefaultConnection.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors."
```

[image]

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Сообщение = Cannot create file 'C:\Users\Root\DefaultConnection.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
  Источник = .Net SqlClient Data Provider
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c.<NonQuery>b__4_0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.<CreateDatabaseFromScript>b__0(DbConnection conn)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.<UsingConnection>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   в System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   в System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   в System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

  Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.AppService.GetAll3() в AppService.cs
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.AppService.TestMain() в AppService.cs
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.AppService.AppService() в AppService.cs
    SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.Program.Main(string[]) в Program.cs
```

[image]

**SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.exe.config**
.\SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw\bin\Debug\SqliteConnectStringConslFrmw.exe.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF6 (.Net Framework) option 1 should work as you can pass it either a ConnectionStringName (from the app.config) or a ConnectionString. However, if you pass a Connection String you need to ensure it is a complete and valid connection string. In your example you are not passing a Provider, If you just want to use the default configured provider and override the connection string, there is an easy work-around:

```
string path = @"C:\Projects\dbAppIndexes3.db";
string connectionString = $"Data Source={path}";

DbContextIndexes dbContextIndexes = new DbContextIndexes(connectionString);

public DbContextIndexes() : base("DefaultConnection")
{ }


public DbContextIndexes(string connectionString) : this () // Use "DefaultConnection" app connection string and provider...
{
    Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; // Overwrite to use the desired connection string.
}
```

If you want to support selecting between different providers you can do something similar offering a provider enumeration to select between SqlLite, SQL Server, etc. alongside the connection string, then create default configs for each provider, such as a DefaultSqlLiteConnection and DefaultSqlServerConnection etc. in the config files:

```
public DbContextIndexes(DbProvider provider, string connectionString)
   : base(provider == DbProvider.SqlServer ? "DefaultSqlServerConnection" : "DefaultSqlLiteConnection")
{
    Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
}
```

Edit: Regarding Error #2 - Yep, there is your issue. In your app.config you have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=dbAppIndexes.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

... defined which would be used and resolves your desired provider when you initialize a `DbContext` with "DefaultConnection". This hasn't carried forward into the final .exe.config. Without that, EF has created a "DefaultConnection.mdf" SQL Server (express?) database, so then telling it to change connection string it won't resolve and result in the original error you were seeing. When you changed the `: base(connectionString)` to pass the "dbAppIndex2" it had created that as an SQL Server database as well. (the mdb/mdf files)

You can manually add the missing `<ConnectionString>...` entry into the .exe.config file and it should start using SqlLite, or try doing a full project clean, check your /bin/debug directory which should be cleared out of all files (I typically delete any /bin and /obj folders after a clean) and do a full rebuild and check the newly populated location. There should be a new .exe.config file containing the connection string setting.

Comment: see **Done-1. Error**

Comment: That is curious, it is still attempting to use the default SQL Server provider, not SqlLite. If you comment out the ` //Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;` in this new constructor and run, which should default to the does it work and still connect to the default SqlLite database, or still hit SQL Server? Check the actual .exe.config file in your runtime folder, and check the folder it is actually executing from to ensure you don't happen to have an outdated .config file that doesn't reflect what is in your app.config source file.

Comment: see **Done-2. Error**

Comment: Yep, updated the answer. Your .exe.config file is missing the <ConnectionStrings> section so it is building a default SQL Server database based on the requested connection string name.